# Is there a way to show configurable tabs in lightning community?

Tags: lightning, lightning-community

I want to show configurable tabs in community but i couldnt find a way to show it in custom templates its only working when i select community with "Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce Communities"

i am talking about "administration" - > "Tabs" - > we have two options there "available tabs" and "selected tabs"
[image]

Is there a way to use this feature in other than "standard tabs + visualforce communities"

I already have "standard tabs + visualforce communities" community but i want to move it to lightning community with custom template but if i'll use that template i am gonna miss this available and selected tab feature so can we do this with custom template also?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "configurable tabs"? What are you trying to achieve? Tabs in general are available in Lightning Communities.

Comment: @JayantDas hey i have updated my question with brief info!!!

Comment: What you have in the screenshot is a way to expose certain tabs in your Community. This is part of the community setup process. You can still do the same thing in any Lightning Community, though the setup process will be different considering the template.

Comment: @JayantDas can you please tell me the setup process for lightning community template ?